# Have to login twice. PHP sessions and login troubles with Chrome and Opera

Tags: php, session, redirect, header

The problem I am encountering is that for my login form I have to login twice for the session to register properly, but only in Chrome (my version is 4.0.249.89) and Opera (my version is 10.10).

Here is the stripped down code that I am testing on:

Login Page:

session_start();

```
 
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 8;
$_SESSION['user_name'] = 'Jim';

session_write_close();
header('Location: http://www.my-domain-name.com/');
exit();
```

Home Page:

```
session_start();
```

if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) )
{
    echo "You are logged in!";
}
else
{
    echo "You are NOT logged in!";
}

Logout Page:

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: http://www.my-domain-name.com/');
exit();
```

Currently, under a fresh load with no cookies, if I go to my-domain-name.com/login/ it will redirect to the home page and say "You are NOT logged in!" but if I go there again it will say "You are logged in!". Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, here are some relevant php.ini directives under Bluehost (most settings should be standard, I haven't changed anything):
session.cookie_domain: no value,
session.cookie_lifetime: 0,
session.cookie_path: /,
session.gc_divisor: 100,
session.gc_maxlifetime: 1440,
session.gc_probability: 1,
session.name: PHPSESSID,
session.save_handler: files,
session.save_path: /tmp,
session.use_cookies: On,
session.use_only_cookies: Off,
session.use_trans_sid: 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `sleep(2);` before issuing the redirect header; that'll tell you whether it's actually a bug in your code somewhere, or if the session data just isn't being written to file fast enough.

Comment: While I was testing your suggestion I happened to notice something. 

I have been testing these pages by going to my-domain-name.com/login, but I happened to try www.my-domain-name.com on one of the attempts and it worked, regardless of the sleep() value or without it altogether.
I can't figure out why this would produce such a result on the non-www url though. Would it be a php.ini setting?

So would that

Comment: A-ha.  The default behavior of PHP's session handler is to issue cookies to the exact domain, including subdomain, the visitor used to get to your page.  To make the cookies applicable to all of your subdomains (including www), call `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.my-domain-name.com');` right before every call to `session_start();` (note the dot at the beginning).  Or, if your PHP installation is only serving one top-level domain, then set `session.cookie_domain` to `.my-domain-name.com` in your php.ini.

Comment: Yes, thank you! That works now. I believe I had even tried setting that directive to my-domain-name.com, without the dot, and it hadn't worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem like this. I Just simply deleted the www. in the header section.

Then it worked fine for me. It will be like this: header('Location: http://my-domain-name.com/');

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as presented, seems that it would cause an infinite redirect loop with the home page calling session_start(), setting the cookie, and instructing the browser to load the home page.  Is there some logic missing from the code presented here?

Comment: `session_start()` is just the command to initialize PHP's built-in session handler.  If a session hasn't been instantiated, it won't redirect to a login page or anything, there just won't be any variables in the `$_SESSION` global variable.