# PHP session lost under Google Chrome OS X build

Tags: php, session, google-chrome, browser-cache

*I hope you won't treat this as a bug report about Google Chrome :)*

My session handler is working fine under all browsers except Google Chrome OS X (build: 12.0.742.122). At random times Chrome lost all session information (shows i am logged in but a single click and i am on the login page again). This is lasts until i clear my whole browser cache then login again, everything is fine until this happen again.

There was a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405633/have-to-login-twice-php-sessions-and-login-troubles-with-chrome-and-opera) question where the accepted answer suggesting to do a `sleep(2)` before checking session variables. I think this isn't the same problem and `sleep` isn't a real solution because it slows down the whole site (every page request delayed with 2 seconds).

Do you think there's a PHP problem here i can fix or is it really a Chrome bug?

Comment: I think this is really a chrome bug - there were a lot of problems with sessions in the past (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2906 - recent last post, you can find more using search there). But it can also be PHP issue, I think you really need to debug it. Just write all HTTP headers and look who sent your cookie session variables last - browser or web server, try to reproduce your problem using custom requests with last working headers etc..

Answer (score 1):

I myself think it is a chromium-bug.

What you can do is ... you can open the chromium-developer-bar (or how ever it's called) by pressing F12 and go to the tab "Network".

Reload your page and keep this tab open. Here you can click on a request and see what cookies are sent during this request/response.

If you have one request where no cookies are sent with you know it's a chromium-bug. If you suddenly get another session-id in the response than you had in the request you should check your php-script :)